# Jquery and javascript scopes

Tags: jquery, scopes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var mySite={};

mySite.title=$('h1');
mySite.makeRed= function(){
return mySite.title.css('color','red');
};


$(document).ready(function() {

mySite.makeRed();


});


</script>
```

Good day. Why does the method called inside the function doesn't return anything?

Comment: Can you explain your question?

Comment: What do you mean by return? You have a problem with the title selector. `mySite.title=$('h1');` will not select the `h1` element at this time, because the DOM is not ready. It must be inside a `$(document).ready()` handler to be able to select that element.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose those script tags are in the HEAD of the document.

When you do this outside the ready handler:

```
 mySite.title=$('h1');
```

The element `h1` does probably not exists yet in the DOM. This is the purpose of the ready handler: make sure the DOM is ready to work with.

You can either move your script tag at the end of the body (right before the `</body>` tag). This has the same result as the ready handler as the DOM is parsed sequentially.

Or you could grab you H1 element inside the ready handler.

Comment: Is there anyway I can initialize and then just call the method upon loading?

Comment: *...Move your script tag at the end of the body (right before the `</body>` tag)...*

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled some things.

```
var mySite={};

mySite.title=$('<h1/>').html("Hello World"); // Set some text and create the tag tag!

mySite.makeRed= function(){
return mySite.title.css('color','red');
};


$(document).ready(function() {



   $("body").append(mySite.makeRed()); // Append it to the dom

});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eZzYz/1/